# Expander IsExpanded method

Tags: c#, expander

I want to know if an expander is expanded or not.
Something like this:

```
Boolean getExpanderStatus= myExpander.isExpanded()
```

But this does not work as
"Non -invocable 'System.Windows.Controls.Expander.IsExpanded' cannot be used like a method.

I'm sure there'll be an annoyingly simple answer to this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsExpanded` is a *property*, not a method.

Properties behave like variables; they don't use parentheses.

Comment: In short: C# is not Java.

Comment: I know it. How can I get the status of the expander?

Comment: @user2514859: By using the value of the property.  `if (myExpander.IsExpanded)`